# Провал аудита: вопрос на самом деле нормальный?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, аудит

Только что [провалил аудит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/68683) в очереди "голосование за закрытие" на следующем вопросе (виден всем, он не удалён и не закрыт):

#### [Звонки в Windows Phone 8.1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491855/181100)

Я счёл, что в вопрос необходимо добавить деталей, чтобы проблему можно было выявить исключительно исходя из вопроса, и **проголосовал за закрытие** по этой причине.

Как видно из происходившего далее, за три дня (плюс-минус) никто не смог понять, в чём именно проблема, пока **автор** сам не ответил на собственный вопрос, связав решение с проблемой, **информации о которой в вопросе не было**.

---

Кто всё-таки прав: я или система? Справедлив ли провал аудита?

Comment: Да вроде нормально выглядит...

Comment: Вы правы конечно, отклонение не справедливо, я его тоже тревожил. Одно здесь ситуация интересна тем, что из самоответа выяснилось, что проблема вызвана "опечаткой и больше не воспроизводится". И закономерен вопрос нужно ли его по этой статье закрывать (имею в виду вопрос конечно :))

Comment: И вообще, у меня возникло впечатление, что после выборов ромбов, контроль дисциплины смягчился,  вопросы стали реже закрывать. Или причина - выход из беты, когда много народа потеряло полномочия в связи с девальвацией рейтинга.

Comment: @Cerbo скорее дело в том, что стало меньше закрывающих участников. Удалять и блокировать сообщения и банить участников стали вроде бы даже чаще. А вот очередь на закрытие стала сразу больше, сейчас в ней аж 103 вопроса.